# Can RestTemplate send form data using GET?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I am having a application to call another API, to pass a serial number and it will return a encrypted value for my client.
To encrypt the number, I have to send a request with two keys within the Body.

API tested on Postman and it working fine
[image]

But while I make a request on JAVA, the API had my request, but it cannot retrieve the form data I passed(i.e. empty). So the number cannot be encrypted properly

```
HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
header.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        
MultiValueMap<String, String> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>(); 
body.add("key1", key1);
body.add("key2", key2);
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, header);
        
String apiUrl = "http://<apiUrl>/<endpoint>?<num>={numToEncrypt}";
String numToEncrypt = "AB 12345678";
RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<String> response = rt.exchange(apiUrl , HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class, numToEncrypt);
```

If the API method changed to POST and I edited related code (from `HttpMethod.GET` to `HttpMethod.POST`), they are working fine.
But API operator do not prefer the changes.

So my question is, is it possible to send form data via GET by using RestTemplate?

I am using `JAVA-1.8` and RestTemplate is from `spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE`

Comment: For forms that use the GET method, the entire form data is sent as part of the query string. But, if we're using the POST method, then its data is sent as part of the body of the HTTP request.

Comment: Do they really need a body with the parameters or can you just add them to the URL? As that is what it looks like you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to send form data via Get using Rest Template, but it is not supported by default, please refer the below link, but for sending form data POST method is recommended approach, may be the below link could help

https://thegeekyasian.com/http-get-request-with-a-request-body-using-resttemplate/